# Prevent WheelUp on !WheelUp

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to send the letter "a" when `ALT` is pressed and the mouse wheel is scrolled up.

This code works partially:

```
!WheelUp::
  Send, a
return
```

In Vscode or just the plain Windows Texteditor however, I notice some scrolling if I scroll to hard with my mouse while pressing `ALT`.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Is that all the code in your script? Do you have other scripts running at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to check for running applications with high priority. These may interfere with AHK. For example I had similar issues while running AIMP (music player) in the background.

Setting the script's priority might be worth trying too.